# MPAndroid barchart display data is incomplete

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

i used barchart and group datas,but it can not display all content and it can not be scrolled .I do not know how to solve it.The library version is "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1" .Thank you for your help! Here's my code:

```
    mChartView.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    XAxis xaxis = mChartView.getXAxis();
    xaxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xaxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM); 
    xaxis.setAxisMinimum(0);  

    YAxis yaxRigth =mChartView.getAxisRight();
    yaxRigth.setAxisMinimum(0);
    yaxRigth.setEnabled(false);  

    YAxis yaxisLeft =mChartView.getAxisLeft();
    yaxisLeft.setAxisMinimum(0); 
    mRandom = new Random(100);
    ArrayList<BarEntry> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> data3 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> data4 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> data5 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> data6 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        data1.add(i, new BarEntry(i, mRandom.nextFloat()*600));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        data2.add(i, new BarEntry(i, mRandom.nextFloat()*500));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        data3.add(i, new BarEntry(i, mRandom.nextFloat()*400));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        data4.add(i, new BarEntry(i, mRandom.nextFloat()*300));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        data5.add(i, new BarEntry(i, mRandom.nextFloat()*200));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        data6.add(i, new BarEntry(i, mRandom.nextFloat()*100));
    }
    BarDataSet dataset1 = new BarDataSet(data1, "Test1");
    BarDataSet dataset2 = new BarDataSet(data2, "Test2");
    BarDataSet dataset3 = new BarDataSet(data3, "Test3");
    BarDataSet dataset4 = new BarDataSet(data4, "Test4");
    BarDataSet dataset5 = new BarDataSet(data5, "Test5");
    BarDataSet dataset6 = new BarDataSet(data6, "Test6");

    dataset1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    dataset2.setColor(Color.RED);
    dataset3.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    dataset4.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    dataset5.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    dataset6.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    BarData data = new   BarData(dataset1,dataset2,dataset3,dataset4,dataset5,dataset6);
    mChartView.setData(data);

    float groupSpace = 0.1f;
    float barSpace = 0.05f; // x6 dataset
    float barWidth = 0.1f; // x6 dataset
    mChartView.getData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
    mChartView.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace);
```

Answer (score -2):

The graph itself is not scrollable.

But you can make it scrollable by putting it in:

1. [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

   or
2. [HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

   or
3. [HorizontalScrollView inside ScrollView](http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/creating-two-dimensions-scroll-view.html) for two dimensional scrolling